# Share on Whatsapp in HTML5 android app (whatsapp://send?text=http://www.example.com)

Tags: android

I am developing an app (webview in Construct 2) which requires some text or link to be shared on whats app.
I am using an offline apk converter (from HTML5 code) to do so.

But when I execute the above link, browser object gives error (like page not available, something like).

So I want to add intent for the above link.
Kindly tell me where or what file , I need to write intent or any other code ?
Is it androidmanifest.xml ? or somewhere else ?
I already understand this is possible in XDK or Cocoon IO. But I really want to understand how this stuff works.
Please explain, project completed only this stuff is pending. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   
 <a href="whatsapp://send?text=The text to share!" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

Works for me on iOS 8 (iPhone 6, latest versions) Android 5 (Nexus 5, latest versions) and windows phone

Comment: I know this, but if this not works, then where to write code and in which file ?

Comment: @prince Refer the following prject in GIthub https://github.com/kriskbx/whatsapp-sharing. Hope this helps